# How to make yourself join a specific channel in discord once someone specific is present?

Tags: c#, discord

I just started getting in to c# and wanted to make something simple. Once a specific user joins any channel in my server, I would automatically join that channel when the user is present.

I was thinking of using the specific id's of the server,channel and user, alongside my token so once it see's that specific user's ID it would automatically join that channel.  Though I'm not sure how to set certain user ID's in code, help would be nice :)

Here is the code that I've done so far to take the users token in to place :

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.Title = "Auto Join Bot lol";
  DiscordSocketClient discordSocketClient = new DiscordSocketClient();
  string str;
  try
  {
    str = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
  }
  catch
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your token:");
    str = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      discordSocketClient.Login(str);
      Console.WriteLine("Successfully logged in!", Color.LightGreen);
      File.Delete("token.txt");
      File.AppendAllText("token.txt", str);
      break;
    }
    catch
    {
      Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Your token might be wrong.", Color.IndianRed);
      Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your token:");
      str = Console.ReadLine();
      File.Delete("token.txt");
      File.AppendAllText("token.txt", str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few bots on my own... but eh, If I'm understanding your question correctly. What you seek is that the bot pushes an user into a channel on a certain event (like when someone joins). I do not think that is possible.

It is possible to make the bot join the channel though, if that is what you seek? I think it is worthwhile for you to adventure into the nuget package DSharpPlus https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus. It is a nuget package for making interaction with the discord API simple.

For instance, interaction with messages is as simple as

```
_discord.MessageCreated += async e => { await _commandList.Run(e); };
```

(message created being an event you can subscribe too, that has MessageCreateEventArgs. MessageCreateEventArgs has a method .Response(string).

As you can see, that is very simple.

Here is the documentation to let the bot join a voice channel for DSharpPlus
https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.VoiceNext.VoiceNextClient.html

I hope this helps you along!

Comment: I wasn't going to use a bot but instead wanted to make it go off of the user (you). It detects if the certain user (friend) is present in any voice chats in a specific server and then instantly joins. Thanks for the documentation though, will definitely help.